# Connecting hi-fi speaker to a 2.5mm jack to get computer sound output

Tags: audio

I hope this question is suitable for this site.

I have an Aiwa NSX-V25.
The two speakers attach to the back of the amplifier via free wires that you connect manually.

I want to attach a 3.5mm jack to the wires (each speaker has two) and plug it into my sound output from my computer. Would that work? If so, which wire should I solder to what part of the 3.5mm jack?

Comment: off-topic: Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Computer speakers are usually powered speakers (often known as monitors) - these have an amplifier built in. The inputs are usually line-level.

HiFi Speakers are usually unpowered and have to be connected to the outputs of a HiFi amplifier.

Your Amplifier may have an Aux-in connector to which you can connect an audio cable from your PC's line-out socket. You can purchase cables with suitable connectors at each end.

Comment: I actually want to get rid of the amplifier altogether to save space and just get the soundcard output out to the speaker. Is that a possibility?

Comment: No, it is not. You need an amplifier. If you are feeling handy, you can put your amplifier inside the speaker if you wish. I also doubt you can solder to a 3.5mm jack directly. They are usually nickel plated. I love this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solderability